# how to add and read resource file from jar

Tags: java, jar, maven

I have hibernate.cfg.xml and test.txt in the path which i read by java program. Now when i created the jar using maven those files were not present. So i read that i should put in the resources folder , so now my directory structure is

> scr -> main-> java
>
> ```
>         ->resources
> ```

Now i can see the files in the jar but they are not inside resource folder 
it bascically

> myjar.jar -> com (source code)
>
> ```
>        -> META -INF
>        -> hibernate.cfg.xml
>        -> test.txt
> ```

I tried accessing using

getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.txt")

but got null..

Let me know what steps are wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html), Does `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.txt")`  make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

`getClass().getResourceAsStream(name)` searches for the resource in the same dir as the class for which this method is called is in.

For instance, you have class `A` and resource `test.txt` in the same dir the you call `getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.txt")`. If it's located in some subdir, you need to express that in `name`: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("subdir/test.txt")`.

I haven't tested that, but looking in dirs above current should be possible with: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("../test.txt")`.