# Getting data periodically from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, activemq-classic

Basically, i've a data table in MySQL.
I want to get all the data, and sent it become message to ActiveMQ (1 message for 1 row in table).

But the data table automatically updated every 5 second. So there is some new data in table for every 5 second.

How to sending the new data without double sending the data that was sent?
And i think i must use the Thread.sleep(5000) for made it endless looping?

This all i got:

```
package testcode;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;


public class ProducerDataBase implements Runnable {

    public String vardbtype;
    public String vardbserver;
    public String vardbuser;
    public String vardbpassword;
    public String vardbname;
    public int batchperiod2;

    public ProducerDataBase() {
        vardbtype = MYSQL;
        vardbserver = mysqltest;
        vardbuser = testadmin;
        vardbpassword = admin;
        vardbname = messages;
        batchperiod2 = 5000;
    }

    public void run(){
        ConnectionFactory factory = null;
        javax.jms.Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        Connection cs = null;
        try {
            factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            connection.start(); 
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            destination = session.createQueue("TestQueue");
            producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            if(vardbtype.equals("MYSQL")){
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                System.out.println("----------------------------");
                Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+ vardbserver, vardbuser, vardbpassword);
                while(true) {
                    Statement stmts = c.createStatement();
                    String sql = ("SELECT * FROM "+ vardbname);
                    ResultSet rss = stmts.executeQuery(sql);
                    while(rss.next()) {
                        String  message = rss.getString("MESSAGE");
                        System.out.println("Message = " + message);
                        TextMessage mssg = session.createTextMessage(message);
                        System.out.println("Sent: " + mssg.getText());
                        producer.send(mssg);
                    }
                    rss.close();
                    stmts.close();

                    Thread.sleep(batchperiod2);
                }
            }
        } catch(JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(session != null) {
                try {
                    session.close();
                } catch (JMSException ex) {
                    // ignore   
                }
            }
            if(connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (JMSException ex) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
    }
}
```

My code works, but it didn't sending the messages again when the table was updated...

Comment: Does your table have any type of timestamp column? It would be much better to find all rows since the last query; Java is not a real time system.

Comment: It didn't... the table only have 1 column that i need to sent row by row to the MQ...

Comment: This really is a bad approach; you'll never be sure about the timing. You'd be much better off implementing a `Trigger` in MySql. "A trigger is defined to activate when a statement inserts, updates, or deletes rows in the associated table. These row operations are trigger events. For example, rows can be inserted by INSERT or LOAD DATA statements, and an insert trigger activates for each inserted row." [Using Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html). Then there is no need to sleep, and every SQL statement will send -- row by row -- the data to MQ.

Comment: Ohh okk got it, so i don't need to sleep.thread to make it loop, but it will works when there is new data too? have u any link references to guide me?

Comment: Link was in the previous comment "[Using Triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466685/how-to-add-and-read-resource-file-from-jar?rq=1)", but just google "mysql triggers"

Comment: Oh yaa, sorry didnt mind it was there lol... thankyou for the references, hopefully it will solve my issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to distinguish rows that have been read from rows that have not been read.

You can either run your program 'forever' and use a sleep to make it wait, or you could run your program from a cron job.

You could do something like:

- store the last id that you read (you might need to write this to a file if you need to stop your program and want it to persist for next time)
- read all the available rows with id > the last id that you read
- loop / or stop and run again later

Or it might make sense to mark the rows in the database as read:

- read all the available rows
- for each row, update the database, set column 'read' = true or something - lots of update statements, might be slow
- loop / or stop and run again later

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion btw...
I've another problem just like this, but it was on PostgreSQL.
And someone suggesting me using a function on PostgreSQL that basically creating a Pseudocolumn (Virtual column) by counting it self, it works and solved the problem.
And i got some reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracle-s-rowid-in-mysql to fix my MySQL issue but i didn't get any way to make the code works...

Comment: Hmm I'm afraid I can't help you with that sorry, I haven't seen that trick before. You might be best to post up a new question for it and someone can help you.